# Python import - NO module found

Tags: python, python-import

Inside Project/networkx/algorithms/isomorphism/  there is a file called isomorph.py. 
It has a line `import networkx as nx`. 
When I try to run the file, I get an error like below:

```
ImportError: No module named networkx
```

I tried changing the pythonpath from /`home/rachana/Downloads/Project` to `/home/rachana/Downloads/` but in vain.

What is the problem here?

Comment: How are you trying to run the file?  What exact command are you using?

Comment: Do you have access to this module? You can additionally change the import command to the exact path of the module you are importing

Comment: Why are you trying to run this file directly? It is a nested submodule of the `networkx` package; it is not meant to be executed directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried installing the missing module? You can simply install it using:

`pip install networkx`